# Disabling scroll wheel while still capturing the event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to handle mouse wheel events without the actual functionality that comes with the event.

Basically I have an event handler for mouse wheel events, and I am outputting some information into a div relating to those events, and am using scrollTop=scrollHeight to keep it scrolled to the bottom so I can constantly see the new lines of output.

what is happening here is every time i scroll in the part of the page with the event listener, it will call this and output the event string to the div as a new line.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
eventHandler = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    const display = document.getElementById('inputDisplayer');
    const msg = document.createElement('div');

    msg.innerText = e.timestamp;
    display.append(msg);
    display.scrollTop = display.scrollHeight;
};
```

The problem here is I can scroll down with no problem and this can even handle any other mouse or keyboard event just as well while displaying the event, but the only problem I have is with scrolling up. It seems like the functionality behind the event happens after it updates the scrollTop according to scrollHeight, so even though my program tries to scroll it to the bottom, the scroll up event will scroll up right after and prevent me from seeing the new line that comes up in the bottom of the div.

Here are some gifs that show what I mean:

This is what it looks like when I click or scroll down, it stays scrolls to the bottom so I can see the newest line:
[left/right clicking and down scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InHQO.gif)

This is what it looks like when I scroll up, as you can see I can see the new line briefly but then the scroll up kicks in.
[scrolling upwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3XGa.gif)

So because of this I am looking of a way to somehow disable the scrolling up mouse function, while still being able to capture the actual scroll up event and keeping the scroll bar on the side.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to disable scrolling but still capture scroll events?

Comment: Essentially yes or any way around this issue, I want to be able to capture my scroll up event and having it display in the div without it scrolling up my div

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
eventHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const display = document.getElementById('inputDisplayer');
    const msg = document.createElement('div');
    msg.innerText = e.timestamp;
    display.append(msg);        
};
```

Also I would move `const display = document.getElementById('inputDisplayer');` outside of the eventHandler to improve performance. Currently it has to rescan the DOM and get the element every time it receives an event.

Comment: preventDefault doesn't seem to do anything for me, I tried multiple events and it seems the only even it prevents is keyboard events, where it won't register the event at all afterwards, scroll wheel and mouse clicks still function just like before